# angular java script shows {{message}} in browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

angular java script shows {{message}} in browser.i tried all possible ways but still sucks.

```js
var myApp=angular.module("mod",[]);
myApp.controller("con", function($scope){
$scope.message = "hhhhhhhh";
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="mod">
    <head>
 <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="sample.js"></script>
 </head>
<body ng-controller="con">
<div>
 {{message}}
</div>
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: shouldn't the second script tag contain "src" not "type" ?!!

Comment: Second script should contain type instead of source

Comment: time to learn to look in browser console for errors thrown and clues as a result...and looking in dev tools network for more clues

Comment: in my text editor i used src instead of type.. but still the browser dispalying {{message}}

Answer (score 1):

Include your sample.js at the end of the body (DOM Manipulation), plus, it's

```
<script src="sample.js"></script>
```

not

```
<script type="sample.js"></script>
```

See the following plunker that works with your code :

https://plnkr.co/edit/jwkd4hzsUrqNQYmG0jCH?p=preview

So maybe you don't have the angular.js file at the following location  `bower_components/angular/angular.js`

So use a CDN instead 
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @charlietfl you're right, I meant at the end not after.

Comment: @imran if it fix your issue, accept the answer please.

Comment: sorrry friend..  doesn't fix the problem.. i want to add the js file as external and when i included the js file within the html file it display an error followed by the java script file contents..

Comment: Adding the js file as external doesn't mean anything.
Include every errors you get by including the sample.js as suggered.
Without errors, we cannot help you.

Comment: @imran please provide better information... Edit your question with the new html, the js, and insert the console message please.

Comment: thanks...now its working...i used double clause instead of single clause in javascript file..that might be the problem.. anyhow very thanks @sorikario

Comment: your code in plunker is what solved my problem.very thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the ng-cloak directive.

```
<html ng-app="mod">
<head>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="sample.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="con">
 <div ng-cloak>
  {{message}}
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: browser is completly blank. nothing shows up friend :(